# xUnit framework: Equivalent of [TestFixtureSetUp] of NUnit in XUnit?

Tags: nunit, xunit

**What is xUnit's equivalent of NUnit's `[TestFixtureSetUp]`?**

We have explored and found that `IUseFixture<T>` is the equivalent of `[TestFixtureSetUp]`, but it's not working as expected.

As we have explored (in case of NUnit), we found that `[TestFixtureSetUp]` marked methods for code to be executed only once before all test in the fixture have been run. In xUnit, the equivalent of `[TestFixtureSetUp]` is `IUseFixture<T>` as we have explored, but during testing, we found that the `SetFixture` method of `IUseFixture` is being called before every test (not only once for all methods).

Please let us know how can we achieve the above in xUnit. Also correct us if we are misunderstanding something. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of `[TestFixtureSetUp]` in XUnit, but you can achieve similar functionality. [This page](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons) lays out the translation between NUnit and XUnit (as well as a couple other C#/.NET test frameworks).  However, XUnit largely got rid of setups/teardowns ([this article](http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html) explains why that decision was made). Instead, you need the test suite to implement an interface called `IUseFixture<T>` which can initialize some data for the fixture.

You might also want to read [this overview of XUnit](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/01/introduction-to-xunit.html), written from the perspective somebody coming from an NUnit/MbUnit background.

Comment: Thanks Laepdjek. We got the point. We can initialize T(of IUseFixture<T>) in its (T's) constructor and it will be shared in all the the test methods.

Comment: Given how xUnit is in general much more intuitive than other testing frameworks, I find it surprising that the solution is so... cumbersome.

Comment: Using a static constructor could be a good workaround for many use cases.

Comment: The old IUseFixture interface in xUnit.net v1.x has been replaced by two new interfaces: IClassFixture and ICollectionFixture. See http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html

Comment: @AlexKlaus The link you sent is not working.